# Azure Devops, multiple on-prem environments, variables per environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure, azure-pipelines

I've configured first deployment pipeline to an on-prem DEV environment.
The project consists of 3 identical environments, DEV, UAT and PROD
While their setup is exactly alike, their config (database credentials etc.) is obviously not.

I'm using the DevOps `variables` to alter `web.config` and `appsettings.json` configuration files while deploying. 
Therefore I'd like to apply the same deployment pipeline, targeting 3 different environments with 3 different variables sets.

This is the way I've seen in Octopus. Is it possible in the DevOps?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a **Release Pipeline** with a stage for every environment; each stage has a different variable group, defining that environment's settings.
On each stage you can copy files, etc. and run tests against the environment.
If the test/stage succeeds, the pipeline goes ahead to the next stage.
Between the stages, you can configure that an authorized person has to approve the next step.
The screenshot below is a release pipeline of one of my little side projects.

[image: release pipeline with multiple stages]

Comment: Yup, this is the best answer!

Comment: This doesn't address the variable aspect of the question

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want a single variable to have different values per stage.  This same concept Octopus took a while to get right with being able to manage the variables.  Currently that isn't a thing that is available in Azure devops.  You can create a pipeline that Ned Flanders suggested but you would need to define the variable multiple times for each environment and scope each variable to the stage it is deployed in.  I think this is a need of azure devops and is one thing that octopus deploy does better than azure devops. I would recommend opening a feature request for this.  Microsoft moved away from user voice and onto developer community.  There is a request for this back in April that got closed in September due to low activity [closed request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/552933/single-pipeline-variable-separate-values-per-stage.html).  If you open up a new one, I'm sure we can get people here to vote on it